# How to debug `create-react-app`s in visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, react-scripts

I tried suggestions made here and in other places, but can't get the vscode debugger to work properly, I.E. breakpoints never become active   and of course they don't break.

The application is normally ran with `npm start` which calls `react-scripts start`.

I've tried these launch configurations:

```
  {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      {
        // I adapted this from a config to debug tests
        "name": "create-react-app",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
        "args": ["start"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to debug the client (JavaScript within the browser) or the server (JavaScript within Node.js?)

Comment: @Wyck well, the app is in typescript, React is obviously a frontend framework, I want to debug the client with source maps that link it to my original ts code on my ide.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your *first* launch configuration is fine, you just need to:

1. start the development server using `npm start` from a separate terminal;
2. press `F5` or the green arrow in VS Code to launch the debugger and open a new
   browser instance.

Reference: [Debugging React](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_debugging-react)

**.vscode/launch.json**

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update**: Edited the answer replacing the deprecated `pwa-chrome` with `chrome`.

Comment: Thanks! I'd read the page you link but obviously didn't pay much attention to that one line `Ensure that your development server is running (npm start). Then press F5 or the green arrow`

Comment: Tante grazie, Mirco! I feel I owe you part of my salary XD

Comment: Ahahah! I'm very pleased to be helpful :)

Comment: Should be `"type": "chrome"` now. Is `"version": "0.2.0"` still needed?

Comment: Thaks @JustinM.Keyes for pointing out the deprecated `type`, I've updated the answer. The version is still required according to the docs. I believe the VS Code team can use it to avoid breaking changes in future releases when updating the syntax.

Answer (score 21):

It is sample projecet react

```
npx create-react-app my_app
```

1 Create Launchjsonfile if you haven't. this automatically create

[image]

2. select web app (chrome)

[image]

3.change port number 8080(default) to 3000 (or your assigned port)

[image]

4.Take package.json. you can see the scripts and you focus on start word the the debug script will automatically suggest click on it .the application run on port localhost:3000

[image]

or

[image]

5.you can check on browser

[image]

6.now add break point on the starting of the application here (where you want)

[image]

7. click Launch chrome

[image]

8. refresh page .now you can see the break point hit

[image]

**How it works(Gif) click on it for better quality**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly improved way of doing this that will start the development server when you click on the green run arrow.

1. Create a `tasks.json` file inside of your `.vscode` folder ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks))
2. Create a new task to start the server

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Start React App",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "npm start",
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/client"
        },
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": {
          "owner": "custom",
          "pattern": {
            "regexp": ".",
            "file": 1,
            "location": 2,
            "message": 3
          },
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": "Compiling...",
            "endsPattern": "Compiled successfully"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

3. Add this task as a `preLaunchTask` to `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch React App",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/client",
            "preLaunchTask": "Start React App"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Over the years I've had to look this up multiple times (because documentation, am I right?) and this is the most concise and clear-to-understand answer I've ever found on the topic. Many thanks.